# VC++ project 64 bit migration issue: Linker error

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, msbuild

I was attempting to migrate VC++ project from Win32 to x64 below is the project configuration for the project
[image]

I am getting the below build errors ( linker)

```
1>ResourceCompile:
1>  Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Resource Compiler Version 6.1.6723.1
1>  
1>  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
1>  
1>  
1>MSVCMRTD.lib(mstartup.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131188) : Inconsistent field declarations in duplicated types (types: tagMSG; fields: <alignment member>): (0x04000037).
1>MSVCMRTD.lib(mstartup.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131188) : Inconsistent field declarations in duplicated types (types: _SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES; fields: <alignment member>): (0x04000044).
1>MSVCMRTD.lib(managdeh.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131188) : Inconsistent field declarations in duplicated types (types: tagMSG; fields: <alignment member>): (0x04000033).
1>MSVCMRTD.lib(managdeh.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131188) : Inconsistent field declarations in duplicated types (types: _SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES; fields: <alignment member>): (0x04000038).
1>MSVCMRTD.lib(managdeh.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131188) : Inconsistent field declarations in duplicated types (types: _TP_CALLBACK_ENVIRON; fields: <alignment member>): (0x0400003e).
1>MSVCMRTD.lib(mehvecdtr.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131188) : Inconsistent field declarations in duplicated types (types: tagMSG; fields: <alignment member>): (0x04000032).
1>MSVCMRTD.lib(mehvecdtr.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131188) : Inconsistent field declarations in duplicated types (types: _SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES; fields: <alignment member>): (0x04000037).
1>MSVCMRTD.lib(mehvecdtr.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131188) : Inconsistent field declarations in duplicated types (types: _TP_CALLBACK_ENVIRON; fields: <alignment member>): (0x04000038).
1>MSVCMRTD.lib(msilexit.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131188) : Inconsistent field declarations in duplicated types (types: tagMSG; fields: <alignment member>): (0x04000037).
1>MSVCMRTD.lib(msilexit.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131188) : Inconsistent field declarations in duplicated types (types: _SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES; fields: <alignment member>): (0x0400003f).
1>MSVCMRTD.lib(msilexit.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131188) : Inconsistent field declarations in duplicated types (types: _TP_CALLBACK_ENVIRON; fields: <alignment member>): (0x0400004a).
1>MSVCMRTD.lib(puremsilcode.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131188) : Inconsistent field declarations in duplicated types (types: tagMSG; fields: <alignment member>): (0x04000032).
1>MSVCMRTD.lib(puremsilcode.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131188) : Inconsistent field declarations in duplicated types (types: _SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES; fields: <alignment member>): (0x04000037).
1>MSVCMRTD.lib(puremsilcode.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131188) : Inconsistent field declarations in duplicated types (types: _TP_CALLBACK_ENVIRON; fields: <alignment member>): (0x0400003d).
1>MSVCMRTD.lib(mstartup.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (8013118D) : Inconsistent layout information in duplicated types (tagMSG): (0x0200003a).
1>MSVCMRTD.lib(mstartup.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (8013118D) : Inconsistent layout information in duplicated types (_SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES): (0x02000044).
1>MSVCMRTD.lib(managdeh.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (8013118D) : Inconsistent layout information in duplicated types (tagMSG): (0x02000035).
1>MSVCMRTD.lib(managdeh.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (8013118D) : Inconsistent layout information in duplicated types (_SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES): (0x0200003a).
1>MSVCMRTD.lib(managdeh.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (8013118D) : Inconsistent layout information in duplicated types (_TP_CALLBACK_ENVIRON): (0x0200003b).
1>MSVCMRTD.lib(mehvecdtr.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (8013118D) : Inconsistent layout information in duplicated types (tagMSG): (0x02000033).
1>MSVCMRTD.lib(mehvecdtr.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (8013118D) : Inconsistent layout information in duplicated types (_SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES): (0x02000038).
1>MSVCMRTD.lib(mehvecdtr.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (8013118D) : Inconsistent layout information in duplicated types (_TP_CALLBACK_ENVIRON): (0x02000039).
1>MSVCMRTD.lib(msilexit.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (8013118D) : Inconsistent layout information in duplicated types (tagMSG): (0x0200003a).
1>MSVCMRTD.lib(msilexit.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (8013118D) : Inconsistent layout information in duplicated types (_SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES): (0x0200003f).
1>MSVCMRTD.lib(msilexit.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (8013118D) : Inconsistent layout information in duplicated types (_TP_CALLBACK_ENVIRON): (0x02000040).
1>MSVCMRTD.lib(puremsilcode.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (8013118D) : Inconsistent layout information in duplicated types (tagMSG): (0x02000035).
1>MSVCMRTD.lib(puremsilcode.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (8013118D) : Inconsistent layout information in duplicated types (_SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES): (0x0200003a).
1>MSVCMRTD.lib(puremsilcode.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (8013118D) : Inconsistent layout information in duplicated types (_TP_CALLBACK_ENVIRON): (0x0200003b).
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1255: link failed because of metadata errors
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:12.02
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

**I was able to solve the above error by changing the struct member alignment from /Zp4 to /Zp16**, however this change is impacting other components, is there any way i can solve this error without changing the structure member alignment?

Comment: Hi, any update about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try these steps:

**Suggestions**

**1)** If you use **CLR**, please follow this:

first disable the **CLR** option if you use by right-click on your project **Properties**-->**Configuration Properties**-->**C/C++**-->**General**-->change the option **Common Language Runtime Support** `/clr` to `No Common ....`.

**Then**, right-click on every cpp file(that actually required the `CLR`) **Properties**-->**C/C++**-->**General**-->**Common Language RunTime Support** `/clr`.

**2)** right-click on the Project **Properties**-->**C/C++**--> set **Debug Information Format** to `Program Database /Zi`.

**3)** add `/clr:nostdlib /AI"%ProgramFiles%\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0"` under **Project Properties**-->**C/C++**-->**Command Line**-->**Additional Options**.

**Also**, set **Enable Minimal Rebuild** to `No(/RM-)` and **Basic Runtime Checks** to `Default` under **C/C++** --> **Code Generation**.

**4)** set **Enable C++ Exceptions** to `No` on the clr-enabled files by right-click on these files->**Properties**-->**C/C++**-->**Code Generation**.

**Besides**, if these do not help, I suggest you could share some code with us to help us troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your response, The current solution is targeted to .net 3.5 , and the method described above requires v4.0, I have tried the same approach but looks like /clr:nostdlib is not supported in .net 3.5

Comment: It seems that you used VC2008 and also what is your specific project type? Did you create a mfc project?

Comment: Or I think you could install [Net Framework 4](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-framework/net40) on your PC and then you can use it.  Besides, as a supplement to the answer, `VC2008` is too old and Microsoft no longer maintains it. So I suggest you could use VS2019 which has more improvements. And you should not worry about version problems and just have a try.  Use `v142`(vc2019) to build your project and in that mode,  And then try my suggestion.

Comment: The project uses /clr:oldsyntax runtime which is depreciated in VS2019 so cant use v142, I have tried to migrated the project to .net 4 and tried the said approach, still facing the same error. It is a MFC project @perry-qian-msft